# Constant freezes on my machine on Desktop PC for 2 years

Tags: windows, nvidia-geforce, directx

My desktop PC is a pretty tough one. For over 2 years I've been using this custom desktop (consisting of all types of parts, will post specs later)

It first started by using an application called Worldcraft which is a map-editor for Quake engine video games when I was active for a couple moments and dragged stuff around, when I was active either in the 3D view and dragged stuff around or my mouse cursor started freaking out in the interface and was ported into the top left corner of my screen. Sometimes I get extra graphic glitches and a second later my screen is black, my monitor receives no signal. this also happens when using Skype's webcam, sometime it happens when using Google Chrome or using VLC in DirectX mode - it is pretty much every program that makes use of of my GPU. It doesn't happen when not having my Nvidia drivers installed so it's most likely a GPU issue.

Another thing is, 2 years ago I still used Windows XP, last year I checked out the Windows 8 Consumer Build, then switched on a fresh install of Windows 7, then back to Windows 8 and then back to Windows 7 again - all in a time span of over 11 months.
I started fresh every time, new drivers etc. so it must be hardware related.
Surprisingly, I have no issues on Ubuntu 12 (using Nvidia's official proprietary driver).

DXDiag Log:

http://pastebin.com/2qFvGfUF

```
   Operating System: Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_gdr.120830-0333)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       System Model: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
               BIOS: Default System BIOS
          Processor: Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E6500  @ 2.93GHz (2 CPUs), ~2.9GHz
             Memory: 2048MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 2048MB RAM
          Page File: 2163MB used, 1930MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 32bit Unicode

---------------
Display Devices
---------------
          Card name: NVIDIA GeForce 9500 GT
       Manufacturer: NVIDIA
          Chip type: GeForce 9500 GT
           DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0640&SUBSYS_2AD7107D&REV_A1
     Display Memory: 1267 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 499 MB
      Shared Memory: 767 MB
       Current Mode: 1600 x 900 (32 bit) (59Hz)
       Monitor Name: Acer X203H
      Monitor Model: X203H
         Monitor Id: ACR009D
        Native Mode: 1600 x 900(p) (59.946Hz)
```

I would like to hear your input on this, maybe you can tell me why it happens. I would like to be certain before acquiring new hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Many freezes are due to overheating the CPU. Check that the fans work, showel the dirt out ot the case, make sure nothing obstructs airflow around the machine.

Comment: Doing that, thanks! Also went into BIOS and put down the CPU frequency down a bit (was at 233, put it down to 180 for now)

Comment: Alright, so I've been monitoring the fan speed for a couple hours now and got another freeze, the CPU temperature wasn't any different than usual (Core 0 at 44°C and Core 1 at 37°C according to SpeedFan)

Comment: Some kind of trouble with the graphics card perhaps (just guessing at random, really).

Comment: Got 3 more freezes last night while trying to move something over to my 2GB USB-Stick, then decided to uninstall the Nvidia display drivers and use Microsoft's instead. Haven't received any freezes since.

Comment: @MarcoHladik, if that finally solved it, report here (take a day or two to make sure).

Comment: It seems like the issue is solved, it might have been dust that went somewhere really deep. I have no clue - basically what happened is that my Windows 7 copy didn't boot anymore and it failed at repairing it - so I started new with Windows XP and tried an old ATI card that I had lying around - sadly that one wasn't detected in the end and I tried putting in the older one I had. Installed drivers etc. and haven't experienced any freezes. I later decided to apply my Vista upgrade and see how that was running - Absolutely perfect. Haven't got freezes for 2 days now! TLDR;Cleaned computer good.